# Ternary Operator using part of the condition as the result Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, shortcut, one-liner

In a ternary or if statement, I often want the value to equal the value of what is being tested for example

```
//b is a integer or '-'
//a should be an integer

const a = b === '-' ? -1 : b
```

The statement I am using for a is

```
const a = expr.match(/.*?\((.*)[a-z].*/)[1]
```

so it would be nice to know if there is a single line way to have it work so i'm not repeating a complicated expression that may change.

Comment: Do you mean that complex expression is `b`?

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the variable first.

```
let b = b = expr.match(/.*?\((.*)[a-z].*/)[1];
const a = b == '-' ? -1 : b;
```

If you really want a one-liner, you can assign `b` within the expression.

```
const a = (b = expr.match(/.*?\((.*)[a-z].*/)[1]) == '-' ? -1 : b;
```

But you should have declared `b` earlier. You can reuse the same temporary variable every time, so you only have to declare it once and use it in all the one-liners.

If you need this pattern in multiple places, define a function.

```
function if_dash(expr) {
    return expr == '-' ? -1 : expr;
}

const a = if_dash(expr.match(/.*?\((.*)[a-z].*/)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get value only one time use below mentioned script.
`var a = (b = expr.match(/.*?\((.*)[a-z].*/)[1]) == '-' ? -1 : b;`